# Rails: Server logs show processing as HTML then JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Please could someone help with my Rails application. For some reason, the server logs process HTML as specified in the controllers but then the logs process as JS as well? There is no respond format in any controller of JS.

What could be the cause of this?

Server logs:

```
Started GET "/events"
Processing by EventsController#index as HTML
...
Completed 200 OK in 441ms (Views: 434.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)

Started GET "/events?_=1234567890987"
Processing by EventsController#index as JS
Parameters: {"_"=>"1234567890987"}
...
Completed 200 OK in 179ms (Views: 174.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably some JS is firing a new `xhr` request on/after page load.

Try opening `developer tools` in your browser, go to `network` tab and monitor the `xhr` request happening.